# Using custom QSqlTableModel from QtQuick QML file

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm getting frustrated here. I implemented a custom `QSqlTableModel` and I can't make it work from inside a QML file. But it works from my C++ code !

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include "tablemodel.h"

MyTableModel::MyTableModel() : QSqlTableModel()
{

    setTable("Event");
    setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
    select();

}
```

and this is my QML definition:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import org.qtproject.examples.calendar.tablemodel 1.0
Window {
visible:true
    width: 640
    height: 400
    minimumWidth: 400
    minimumHeight: 300
    color: "#f4f4f4"

    title: "Table example"

     MyTableModel{
         id : myModel
     }

    TableView{
        model:myModel
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

This is the main file, the commented code works, but i want to show the table from inside QML.

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTableView>


#include "qtquickcontrolsapplication.h"
#include "sqleventmodel.h"
#include "tablemodel.h"
#include "mytableview.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("test");
    if (!db.open()) {
        qFatal("Cannot open database");
    }


  QtQuickControlsApplication app(argc, argv);
  qmlRegisterType<MyTableModel>("org.qtproject.examples.calendar.tablemodel", 1, 0, "MyTableModel");

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));

  return app.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?